# docker-compose.yml - yaml: could not find expected ':'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create a docker-compose.yml file from 0 following this [guide.](https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/docker-media-server-2022/#4_Docker_and_Docker_Compose_Usage)

When I try to run the container I get the following error: `yaml: line 29: could not find expected ':'`

I've read everywhere and I find indentation problems, but I haven't been able to tell why my file won't run, any help would be Highly apreciated. My docker-compose.yml file contains the following:

```
version: "3.9"
########################### NETWORKS
# You may customize the network subnet (192.168.89.0/24) below as you please.
# Docker Compose version 3.5 or higher required to define networks this way.

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
  npm_proxy:
    name: npm_proxy
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.89.0/24
########################### EXTENSION FIELDS
# Helps eliminate repetition of sections
# More Info on how to use this: https://github.com/htpcBeginner/docker-traefik/pull/228

# Common environment values
x-environment: &default-tz-puid-pgid
  TZ: $TZ
  PUID: $PUID
  PGID: $PGID

# Keys common to some of the core services that we always to automatically restart on failure
x-common-keys-core: &common-keys-core
  networks:
    - npm_proxy
  security_opt:
    - no-new-privileges:true
  restart: always

# Keys common to some of the dependent services/apps
x-common-keys-apps: &common-keys-apps
  networks:
    - npm_proxy
  security_opt:
    - no-new-privileges:true
  restart: unless-stopped

# Keys common to some of the services in media-services.txt
x-common-keys-media: &common-keys-media
  networks:
    - npm_proxy
  security_opt:
    - no-new-privileges:true
  restart: "no"

########################### SERVICES
services:
################ FRONTENDS
# Nginx Proxy Manager - Reverse Proxy with LetsEncrypt
  npm:
    <<: *common-keys-core # See EXTENSION FIELDS at the top
    container_name: nginx-proxy-manager
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    # For Static IP
    networks:
    # For Static IP
      npm_proxy:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.89.254 # You can specify a static IP
    # For Dynamic IP
    # networks:
    #  - npm_proxy
    ports:
      - '80:80' # Public HTTP Port. Port Forwarding on Router is ON.
      - '443:443' # Public HTTPS Port. Port Forwarding on Router is ON.
      - '81:81' # Admin Web Port. Port Forwarding on Router is OFF. Internal Home Network Access only - 192.168.89.254:81.
    volumes:
      - $DOCKERDIR/appdata/npm/config:/config
      - $DOCKERDIR/appdata/npm/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - $DOCKERDIR/appdata/npm/data:/data
    environment:
      DB_SQLITE_FILE: "/config/database.sqlite"
      DISABLE_IPV6: 'true'
```

I've tried reviewing the indentation, and changing some environment variables definitions ex:
`TZ: $TZ` to `- TZ=$TZ`

Comment: The lines that say `no-new-privileges:true` are missing spaces after the colons.  I might remove _all_ of the `networks:` blocks – use the `default` network with its default configuration – and that might trim things down enough to not need the anchor blocks.

Comment: Start deleting things until you get a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok! So I found out what the problem was, since I was following the guide posted, it had code blocks where you can copy/paste parts of the docker-compose file.

I was using nano to modify the file using SSH to connect to my home server, I was getting tired of using that so I pasted my code on VSCode and found out that some of the blank spaces where not spaces but U+00a0 characters, I simply used find and replace tool to change this characters into a space character and it worked!

Thanks everyone for the quick replies

Answer (score 0):

On my VSCode, your code showed 29 errors.

Here is a version with none, please try what happens:

```css
version: "3.9"
########################### NETWORKS
# You may customize the network subnet (192.168.89.0/24) below as you please.
# Docker Compose version 3.5 or higher required to define networks this way.

networks:
  default:
   driver: bridge
  npm_proxy:
   name: npm_proxy
   driver: bridge
   ipam:
    config:
     - subnet: 192.168.89.0/24
########################### EXTENSION FIELDS
# Helps eliminate repetition of sections
# More Info on how to use this: https://github.com/htpcBeginner/docker-traefik/pull/228

# Common environment values
x-environment: &default-tz-puid-pgid
 TZ: $TZ
 PUID: $PUID
 PGID: $PGID

# Keys common to some of the core services that we always to automatically restart on failure
x-common-keys-core: &common-keys-core
 networks:
  - npm_proxy
 security_opt:
  - no-new-privileges:true
 restart: always

# Keys common to some of the dependent services/apps
x-common-keys-apps: &common-keys-apps
 networks:
  - npm_proxy
 security_opt:
  - no-new-privileges:true
 restart: unless-stopped

# Keys common to some of the services in media-services.txt
x-common-keys-media: &common-keys-media
 networks:
  - npm_proxy
 security_opt:
  - no-new-privileges:true
 restart: "no"

########################### SERVICES
services:
################ FRONTENDS
# Nginx Proxy Manager - Reverse Proxy with LetsEncrypt
  npm:
    <<: *common-keys-core # See EXTENSION FIELDS at the top
    container_name: nginx-proxy-manager
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    # For Static IP
    networks:
    # For Static IP
      npm_proxy:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.89.254 # You can specify a static IP
    # For Dynamic IP
    # networks:
    #  - npm_proxy
    ports:
      - '80:80' # Public HTTP Port. Port Forwarding on Router is ON.
      - '443:443' # Public HTTPS Port. Port Forwarding on Router is ON.
      - '81:81' # Admin Web Port. Port Forwarding on Router is OFF. Internal Home Network Access only - 192.168.89.254:81.
    volumes:
      - $DOCKERDIR/appdata/npm/config:/config
      - $DOCKERDIR/appdata/npm/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - $DOCKERDIR/appdata/npm/data:/data
    environment:
      DB_SQLITE_FILE: "/config/database.sqlite"
      DISABLE_IPV6: 'true'
```